# How to increase the text value on click of button?

Tags: android

I want to increase the value of the text on the click of abutton. However, I want to increase the value by certain amount. My initial value is 250 and I want to increase the textvalue by 250 every time i click on button.

I have written logic for it but the value increases by one.

This is the relevant code:

```
public class SelectCartListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mcontext;

    private static int counter = 250;
    private String stringVal;

    public SelectCartListViewAdapter(Context c){
        mcontext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //... some other code

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Log.d("src", "Increasing value...");
              counter++;
              stringVal = Integer.toString(counter);
              tv1.setText(stringVal);
            }
        });

        //...some other code

        return myView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not include unimplemented methods, boilerplate TODO comments, or code that is commented out and not directly relevant. Do not even include code that doesn't have relevance to what you're asking. Please also format your code responsibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have used a incremental operator here,

```
 counter++;
```

Incremental operator will increase value by one only.

It should be something like this,

```
counter= counter+actualValue;
```

Comment: I am using listview.In each row I have Button and textview.And when I am increasing value of one row.And when I am going to another row its taking previous row value and increasing.Why its happening?..What should I add?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int counter=0, staticCounter=250;

@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            counter= counter+staticCounter;

                    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace part of your code with the below code fragment.

```
 ImageButton button = (ImageButton)myView.findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            //private int _counter;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                //Toast.makeText(mcontext,"Button is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Log.d("src", "Increasing value...");
                 counter+=250;
                    stringVal = Integer.toString(counter);
                    tv1.setText(stringVal);


//              int value = (Integer.parseInt((String) tv1.getText()))+250;
//              tv1.setText(value);

            }
        });
```

Comment: I am using listview.In each row I have Button and textview.And when I am increasing value of one row.And when I am going to another row its taking previous row value and increasing.Why its happening?..What should I add.

Comment: If you're writing answer, please take the time to format the code and remove, at the least, boilerplate TODOs. You are obfuscating your own answer.